# Uncaught ReferenceError: NPObject deleted

Tags: google-chrome-extension, npapi

i get an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: NPObject deleted", when i run my chrome extension. Atm i just noted where the .dll file is in manifest, maybe it's not meant to work like that, but i couldn't read that you have to install it anywhere on chrome site.
So anyone knows what's the origin on this error?

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<embed type="application/x-npNewPlugin" id="pluginId">  
<script src='Test.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

changing `<embed>` with `<object>` does not change the result
my JavaScript:

```
  var plugin = document.getElementById("pluginId");
  var result = plugin().valid;
  console.log("my plugin returned: " + result);
```

and my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "npNewPlugin",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "plugins": [
    { "path": "npNewPlugin.dll"}
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup":"Test.htm"
  }
}
```

When i go to CMD and `regsvr32` the `.dll` file, then everything load correctly, but agen i don't think that you have to register it.

Answer (score 0):

To use your npApi plugin not need call

```
plugin()
```

Use follow

```
 var plugin = document.getElementById("pluginId");
 var result = plugin.valid;
 console.log("my plugin returned: " + result);
```

Read https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html

Comment: it gives `Undefined` when i but in `plugin.valid`and when i but in an `plugin.testEvent()`
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'testEvent'`

Comment: I used FireBreath to create the `.dll` file. and when i try it out in a browser it works, but not in extension ..

Comment: Ofc my plugin is always on looking for blugin mode, even when its listed in chrome plugins list